# How to truncate domain part from username in pam_mount?

Tags: networking, mount, samba, pam, active-directory

I am currently experimenting with the new Active Directory Features in Ubuntu 22.04. I joined the domain with my client and everything worked fine so far. However I want to mount the users home directories from a remote samba share using kerberos. I didn't manage to get pam_mount working so far. Tthere is one flaw:

The user logs in with username@domain. So %(USER) expands do username@domain in the pam_mount.conf.xml. But I just need the "username" part. The home directory is located under /home/username not /home/username@domain. Is there any way to achieve this?

I hope I could explain my problem. This is my first question here. Feel free to ask for any details I forgot to mention.

Comment: Are you just pulling the information from the `pam_mount.conf.xml` file?  If so, you can use `awk` like `awk -F@ '/username/ {print$1}' pam_mount.conf.xml` that way it doesn't show you the `@domain` part of it.

Comment: No, I want pam_mount to use only the username part when mounting the share. Sorry I was unprecise there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently experiencing the same problem, and my research has led me to a couple of potential solutions. According to the [documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/pam_mount.conf.5.html) for pam_mount on Ubuntu in **Variables** section, one approach to addressing this issue is by leveraging winbind. But I haven't yet found a tutorial that explains how to clearly set it up.

Alternatively, you can get rid of the "@domain" by modifying `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
[domain/yourdomain]
...
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
...
```

Work fine with pam_mount and AD! Variable `%(DOMAIN_USER)` gives you `user` instead of `user@domain`
I hope this helps, and please let me know if you find a resolution or if you have any other suggestions.